# Seeing directories of running docker container

Tags: windows, powershell, docker

I build a Docker image. And I want to see what is in the Docker container. So I tried running the following command into powershell:

```
docker exec -ti c4609ec41e73 powershell
```

A powershell is launched but I cannot do anything in there. All I see is

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

How can I launch this powershell into the running container, Io that i can check what exactly is installed?

Some help is much appreciated.

```
FROM jetbrains/teamcity-agent:latest-windowsservercore AS tools

SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]

FROM microsoft/dotnet-framework-build:4.7.1-windowsservercore-ltsc2016

ENV CONFIG_FILE="C:/BuildAgent/conf/buildAgent.properties" \
    JRE_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\Oracle\jre" \
    NUGET_XMLDOC_MODE=skip \
    DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT=true \
    DOTNET_SKIP_FIRST_TIME_EXPERIENCE=true

EXPOSE 9090

VOLUME C:/BuildAgent/conf

COPY --from=tools /BuildAgent /BuildAgent
COPY --from=tools ["C:/Program Files/Git", "C:/Program Files/Git"]
COPY --from=tools ["C:/Program Files/Mercurial", "C:/Program Files/Mercurial"]
COPY --from=tools ["C:/Program Files/Java/Oracle", "C:/Program Files/Java/Oracle"]
COPY --from=tools ["C:/Program Files/Java/OpenJDK", "C:/Program Files/Java/OpenJDK"]
#COPY ["/MSBuild/12.0", "C:/Program Files (x86)/MSBuild/12.0"]
#COPY ["/MSBuild/14.0", "C:/Program Files (x86)/MSBuild/14.0"]
COPY --from=tools ["C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio", "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio"]

# Install Nod
#RUN [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12; Invoke-WebRequest https://nodejs.org/dist/v8.10.0/node-v8.10.0-x64.msi -OutFile nodejs.msi; \
#   Start-Process msiexec -Wait -ArgumentList /q, /i, nodejs.msi; \
#   Remove-Item -Force nodejs.msi

CMD ./BuildAgent/run-agent.ps1
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out if your own windows system has this folder *VisualStudio\v15.0\ folders*
because due to your dockerfile

```
COPY --from=tools ["C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio", "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio"]
```

I think this copys do the job like copy *C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio* from your system to your image.

### -------------------------Old answer below-----------------------------------------------------

I think your operation system is windows.
I am not sure if your docker image is also windows-based image, because most of containers are based on ubuntu.

Let's suppose your container is based on ubuntu, you should just run the container first like

```
docker run -it --rm your_image
```

you just created a container from image your_image. Every container has an unique container_ID.

```
-it: interactive terminal
--rm: remove the container when you get out of it
```

When you run the image, and get in to the contaier, that means you are in the ubuntu system(in the container), it should looks like

```
root@2be3d9fd944:_
```

and then you can type

```
apt list --installed
```

to see what you installed under your ubuntu system, and this all happens in the container.

Suppose you are working with windows OS and have a docker image which is also based on windows(here are some[official windows image base](https://hub.docker.com/u/microsoft/)), but run docker image are always the same.

```
docker run -it [other_options] IMAGE_ID
```

and you are in the container, do what you familiar with windows shell.

### -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

If you don't use option -it(interactive terminal), you can do just as like in you question. 
You can run a command in a running container like following

```
docker run [other_options] IMAGE_ID
```

now you created a container from IMAGE_ID, and you get a container_ID, you can do

```
docker ps
```

to see container informations,and do

```
docker exec -it [other_OPTIONS] CONTAINER_ID COMMAND [ARG...]
```

to run the -it option.

Please read more [Official docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/) to make yourself more clear what is exactly docker does, that saves your time actually.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am not using ubuntu. I installed team city agent. I build the image and I ahve an container. I launched the powershell and I see my folders but when I type cd "Program Files" it gives me the error that it doesnt exist. But I see the folder when I do dir.

Comment: it would be great if you can put some part of your dockerfile, Because I have no sure if the os in your container is also windows, I didn't saw people use windows os in a container. Could you please tell me the os in your container, I know the os of your computer is windows,but what's in container matters.

Comment: I will add it to the main post. The error I get is:  The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets" was not found

When i check in the container powershell I mist the VisualStudio\v15.0\ folders. In the microsoft folder I only have Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions & NuGet.